# Not Showing Data from Api In DataTable

Tags: flutter, datatable, flutter-web, flutter-animation

hi i have json like this:

```
"data": {
        "list_item": [
            {
                "item": "1",
                "item_date": "1669189813143566825",
                "item_id": "0",
                "item_info": {},"
                "item_status":"on",
                    }]}
```

this class with sample table worked for me!but my table in app used paginated table and not worked in.

```
class TableSamleNew extends StatefulWidget {
  const TableSamleNew({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TableSamleNew> createState() => _TableSamleNewState();
}

class _TableSamleNewState extends State<TableSamleNew> {
  final getListController = Get.put(GetListController());
  late List<ListItem>? listItem=getListController.getListClient!.data!.listItem;
```

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
return Scaffold(
  body: GetBuilder<GetListController>(
      builder: (_) => getListController.isLoading
          ? const Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:50),
        child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      ): DataTable(columns: [
      DataColumn(label: Text("1")),
      DataColumn(label: Text("1")),
      DataColumn(label: Text("1")),
      DataColumn(label: Text("1")),
      DataColumn(label: Text("1"))
    ],rows: listItem!.map<DataRow>((e) => DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(Text(e.itemInfo!.clientMobile.toString())),
      DataCell(Text(e.itemId.toString())),
      DataCell(Text(e.itemId.toString())),
      DataCell(Text("")),
      DataCell(Text("")),
    ])).toList()),
  ),
);
```

}
}

this is my main table and not showing data..
table with paginated and sort data and search with one field in table but output showing me null

```
     class DataTableWithSortTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const DataTableWithSortTest({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<DataTableWithSortTest> createState() => _DataTableWithSortTestState();
}

class _DataTableWithSortTestState extends State<DataTableWithSortTest> {
  final getListController = Get.put(GetListController());
  late List<ListItem>? listItem=getListController.getListClient!.data!.listItem;
  bool sort = true;
  onsortColum(int columnIndex, bool ascending) {
    if (columnIndex == 0) {
      if (ascending) {
        listItem!.sort((a, b) => a.itemStatus!.compareTo(b.itemStatus!));
      } else {
        listItem!.sort((a, b) => b.itemStatus!.compareTo(a.itemStatus!));
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {

    listItem = listItem!.cast<ListItem>();
    super.initState();
  }

  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(listItem);

    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Scaffold(

          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Theme(
                        data: ThemeData.light()
                            .copyWith(cardColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor),
                        child: PaginatedDataTable(
                          sortColumnIndex: 0,
                          sortAscending: sort,
                          header: Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                            child: TextField(
                              controller: controller,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "search with name"),
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  listItem = listItem!
                                      .where((element) =>
                                      element.itemStatus!.contains(value))
                                      .toList();
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          source: RowSource(
                            listItem: listItem,
                            count: listItem?.length,
                          ),

                          rowsPerPage: 5,
                          columnSpacing: 5,
                          columns: [
                            DataColumn(
                                label: const Text(
                                  "1",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 14),
                                ),
                                onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    sort = !sort;
                                  });

                                //  onsortColum(columnIndex, ascending);
                                }),
                            const DataColumn(//
                              label: Text(
                                "2",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 14),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const DataColumn(
                              label: Text(
                                "3",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 14),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const DataColumn(
                              label: Text(
                                "4",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 14),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const DataColumn(
                              label: Text(
                                "5",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 14),
                              ),
                            ),


                          ],

                        ),
                      )),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),

                ],
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}

class RowSource extends DataTableSource {


  var listItem;
  final count;
  RowSource({
    required this.listItem,
    required this.count,
  });

  @override
  DataRow? getRow(int index) {
    if (index < rowCount) {
      return recentFileDataRow(listItem![index]);
    } else
      return null;
  }

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get rowCount => count;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;

}

DataRow recentFileDataRow(var listItem) {


  return const DataRow(


    cells: [
      DataCell(Text("")),
      DataCell(Text("")),
      DataCell(Text("")),
      DataCell(Text("")),
      DataCell(Text("")),


    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69631753/13997210)

Comment: thank you but im not use a future directly and use the List<ListItem> not use in the future builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define these variable out of `build` methode:

```
late List<ListItem>? listItem =getListController.getListClient!.data!.listItem;
```

every time the widget rebuild you variable redefine and became empty.

Comment: also could you include getListClient ?

Comment: thanks for response when define these varible out of build method Error like This        
 The instance member 'getListController' can't be accessed in an initializer. (Documentation)  Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. @ImanYarahmadi

Comment: thank you ..your response usefull in another class in my app..but my table like before is null..actually i use 3 diffrent way for show data in table ..but now working?in your opinion how can generate table dynamic in flutter?

Comment: could you include the part that you create your data? I mean getListClient.

Comment: update my post ....please check it

Comment: I think the reason you get empty list is that you are not calling init,

Comment: thank you ....
in your opinion my table is correct?

Comment: when calling it printing my json in console and not problem to run init

Comment: could you print listItem before returning Scaffold and show me the result?

Comment: thank you amirhossein its worked but with smaple table like my code is up...but my table is diffrenet and use the paginated table with sort and .. and not worked ...updated my post and could you look the code again?thank you

Comment: now with sample table worked for me and i can show data to table...but my main table is complex ..update my post please look it

Comment: I didn't get you new issue? was it the problem with the initializer or some where else?

Comment: yes i think problem initializer and sample table up worked..post updated and added main table in post and show me message null table..thank you for time

Comment: can you see my update post?

Comment: sorry I can't help you with that part, may some other people code help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TableSamleNew extends StatefulWidget {
  const TableSamleNew({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TableSamleNew> createState() => _TableSamleNewState();
}

class _TableSamleNewState extends State<TableSamleNew> {
  final getListController = Get.put(GetListController());
ValueNotifier<List<ListItem>> listItemNotifier = ValueNotifier([]);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    listItemNotifier.value=getListController.getListClient!.data!.listItem;

    return Scaffold(
       body: ValueListenableBuilder(
       valueListenable: listItemNotifier, 
       builder:(context,List<ListItem> items, child) =>
          DataTable(columns: [
          DataColumn(label: Text("1")),
          DataColumn(label: Text("1")),
          DataColumn(label: Text("1")),
          DataColumn(label: Text("1")),
          DataColumn(label: Text("1"))
       ],rows: items.map<DataRow>((e) => DataRow(cells: [
          DataCell(Text(e.itemId.toString())),
          DataCell(Text(e.itemId.toString())),
          DataCell(Text(e.itemId.toString())),
          DataCell(Text(e.itemId.toString())),
          DataCell(Text(e.itemId.toString())),
          ])).toList()),
       );
    );
  }
}
```

try to use `ValueNotifier`

Comment: show this error in rows : The argument type 'ValueListenableBuilder<List<ListItem>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<DataRow>'.

Comment: Oh yeah, I make changes, please see now

Comment: thank but again error : The return type 'Iterable<DataRow>' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context. (Documentation)

Comment: Sorry, please try last time, it's will work

Comment: thank you but not working