# How to populate DataTable widget with data fetched from my API?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-datatable

So I try the code from following stack overflow answer [How to populate DataTable with JSON API in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69630552/how-to-populate-datatable-with-json-api-in-flutter), and changed that as per my need but DataTable is not populated and displaying my error message "No data found...". I'm adding whatever I've tried so, it will be easy whoever have worked with DataTable in past.

Thank you in advance.

```
  List applicants = [];
  String applicantsByDate = "http://localhost:3000/applicants/getApplicantsByDate";

  DataRow _resultsAPI(index, data) {
    return DataRow(
      cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(
          Text(
            data['id'],
          ),
        ), //add name of your columns here
        DataCell(
          Text(
            data['firstName'],
          ),
        ),
        DataCell(
          Text(
            data['lastName'],
          ),
        ),
        DataCell(
          Text(
            data['createdAt'],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

 Future<List?> fetchApplicants() async {
      http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(applicantsByDate));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        setState(() {
          applicants = data['applicantsByDate'];
        });
        return jsonDecode(response.body);
      }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
          child: Image.asset(
              "images/Logo.png",
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height: 20.00,
              width: 20.00),
        ),
        leadingWidth: 130,
        title: const Text('Applicants'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: fetchApplicants(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  applicants = snapshot.data;
                  if (applicants.length != 0) {
                    return Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 30.0,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                children: [
                                  DataTable(
                                    columns: const [
                                      DataColumn(
                                        label: Text(
                                          'ID',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Palette.coloresCRC,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                              fontSize: 18),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      DataColumn(
                                        label: Text(
                                          'First Name',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Palette.coloresCRC,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                              fontSize: 18),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      DataColumn(
                                        label: Text(
                                          'Last Name',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Palette.coloresCRC,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                              fontSize: 18),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      DataColumn(
                                        label: Text(
                                          'Date Applied',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Palette.coloresCRC,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                              fontSize: 18),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                    rows: List.generate(
                                      applicants.length,
                                      (index) => _resultsAPI(
                                        index,
                                        applicants[index],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Row(
                      children: const <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          // ignore: sort_child_properties_last
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          width: 30,
                          height: 30,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
                          child: Text('No Data Found...'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                } else {
                  return Row(
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        // ignore: sort_child_properties_last
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
                        child: Text('No Data Found...'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT: Here is what Im getting from my API call, it works as it should

```
   {
        "applicantsByDate": [
            {
                "id": 1007,
                "firstName": "Andrea",
                "lastName": "Savillon",
                "createdAt": "2022-12-14T19:58:57.431Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 1006,
                "firstName": "Emily",
                "lastName": "Savillon",
                "createdAt": "2022-12-14T19:56:42.795Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 1005,
                "firstName": "Andres",
                "lastName": "Abadie",
                "createdAt": "2022-12-14T19:54:03.424Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 1004,
                "firstName": "Carlos",
                "lastName": "Marroquin",
                "createdAt": "2022-12-14T18:05:42.157Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 1003,
                "firstName": "Sara",
                "lastName": "Savillon",
                "createdAt": "2022-12-14T18:03:41.343Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 1002,
                "firstName": "Alexander",
                "lastName": "Savillon",
                "createdAt": "2022-12-14T17:28:38.909Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "firstName": "Miguel",
                "lastName": "Madrid",
                "createdAt": "2022-12-13T21:59:48.593Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "firstName": "Eder",
                "lastName": "Savillon",
                "createdAt": "2022-12-13T14:54:42.118Z"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Please check you api call. May be you're not getting any data from api and I you're getting data then please share what you're getting from api.

Comment: My api call responds as it should, I've edited the post so you can see the api response

Comment: So, you mean you're getting data from api still its going inside else (not in snapshot.hasData)?

Comment: Yes, always going inside else. Want to know why or if Im doing something wrong about it

Comment: Hey, please join this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250445/how-to-populate-datatable-widget-with-data-fetched-from-my-api . I'll help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are somethings that I would change in your code and yor API response:

1. In your API response, this record has another structure:  "primerNombre" y "primerApellido"

   ```
   {
      "id": 1004,
      "primerNombre": "Carlos",
      "primerApellido": "Marroquin",
      "createdAt": "2022-12-14T18:05:42.157Z"
   }
   ```
2. Another important point is the return of your `fetchApplicants()` function, why would you process the data and return the raw? and your FutureBuilder is especting a List not a Map(data).

   ```
   Future<List?> fetchApplicants() async {
      http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(applicantsByDate));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        applicants = data['applicantsByDate'];
        return applicants;
      }
   ```

   }
3. In the `_resultsAPI` function you must retrieve a String for the content of the `Text()` widget so you should use: `data['id'].toString()`

**I've copied your string to locally and make it work:**
[image]

The full code should look something like this:

```
class ResulstsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  ResulstsScreen({super.key});

  List applicants = [];

  String applicantsByDate =
      "http://localhost:3000/applicants/getApplicantsByDate";

  DataRow _resultsAPI(index, data) {
    return DataRow(
      cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(
          Text(
            data['id'],
          ),
        ), //add name of your columns here
        DataCell(
          Text(
            data['firstName'],
          ),
        ),
        DataCell(
          Text(
            data['lastName'],
          ),
        ),
        DataCell(
          Text(
            data['createdAt'],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Future<List?> fetchApplicants() async {
    //var data = jsonDecode(
        //'{"applicantsByDate": [{"id": 1007,"firstName": "Andrea","lastName": "Savillon","createdAt": "2022-12-14T19:58:57.431Z"},{"id": 1006,"firstName": "Emily","lastName": "Savillon","createdAt": "2022-12-14T19:56:42.795Z"},{"id": 1005,"firstName": "Andres","lastName": "Abadie","createdAt": "2022-12-14T19:54:03.424Z"},{"id": 1004,"firstName": "Carlos","lastName": "Marroquin","createdAt": "2022-12-14T18:05:42.157Z"},{"id": 1003,"firstName": "Sara","lastName": "Savillon","createdAt": "2022-12-14T18:03:41.343Z"},{"id": 1002,"firstName": "Alexander","lastName": "Savillon","createdAt": "2022-12-14T17:28:38.909Z"},{"id": 2,"firstName": "Miguel","lastName": "Madrid","createdAt": "2022-12-13T21:59:48.593Z"},{"id": 1,"firstName": "Eder","lastName": "Savillon","createdAt": "2022-12-13T14:54:42.118Z"}]}');

     http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(applicantsByDate));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      
    applicants = data['applicantsByDate'];
    return applicants;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
          child: Image.asset("images/Logo.png",
              fit: BoxFit.cover, height: 20.00, width: 20.00),
        ),
        leadingWidth: 130,
        title: const Text('Applicants'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: fetchApplicants(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  applicants = snapshot.data;
                  if (applicants.length != 0) {
                    return Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 30.0,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                children: [
                                  DataTable(
                                    columns: const [
                                      DataColumn(
                                        label: Text(
                                          'ID',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                              fontSize: 18),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      DataColumn(
                                        label: Text(
                                          'First Name',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                              fontSize: 18),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      DataColumn(
                                        label: Text(
                                          'Last Name',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                              fontSize: 18),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      DataColumn(
                                        label: Text(
                                          'Date Applied',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                              fontSize: 18),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                    rows: List.generate(
                                      applicants.length,
                                      (index) => _resultsAPI(
                                        index,
                                        applicants[index],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Row(
                      children: const <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          // ignore: sort_child_properties_last
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          width: 30,
                          height: 30,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
                          child: Text('No Data Found...'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                } else {
                  return Row(
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        // ignore: sort_child_properties_last
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
                        child: Text('No Data Found...'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As for your first recommendation on the API structure, I made a translate from spanish to English when posting the API response to be more understandable what the structure is meant to be, forgot to translate the one you point, so my bad.

Comment: For the rest, you're also right i was returning raw response and not the Map, and added .toString to data[id] and worked wonderfully, so thank you very much. I will mark your answer as correct.